# Use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to construct orthonormal bases for the subspaces of Rn spanned by the following set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For part c:

[image]

How can I quickly tell that the dimension of the subspace is 2? I used the algorithm and got "3" basis vectors before realising that the 3rd one was parallel to one of the others and therefore not valid. Is there are way to determine before you do this calculation that dim=2 ?

Comment: The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n$, not $2$.  You mean that the dimension of the *subspace* is $2$.  To compute the dimension, just row reduce a matrix with those vectors as rows and count the number of pivots.  Or, when you do Gram-Schmidt, just throw out the vector if you get $0$.

Comment: If you ended up with three vectors, you did something wrong. G-S will spit out a 0 when applied to a vector that’s in the span of the basis vectors that you’ve generated up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

In order to figure out the dimension of a subspace given the basis, follow these steps:

1. Make a matrix where each row is one of the vectors in the basis.
2. Use a calculator to put this matrix in reduced row echelon form.
3. Count the number of non-zero rows. The number of non-zero rows is the dimension of the subspace.

If you don't understand why this procedure works because your Linear Algebra class hasn't gotten to it yet, I can show you some resources that explain it, but usually, this is explained before the Gram-Schmidt procedure. In the case of your problem, [using this method shows a matrix with $2$ non-zero rows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=reduced+row+echelon+form&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22ReducedRowEchelon%22,+%22theMatrix%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B1,+-2,+1,+3,+-1%7D,+%7B0,+6,+-2,+-6,+0%7D,+%7B4,+-2,+2,+6,+-4%7D%7D%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D), so we now know that the dimension of the subspace is $2$.